# How to change file.status in ant Upload component as "done" after getting status code 200 in my customRequest props?

Tags: c#, reactjs

I am using ant design Upload component to upload files in my React application (TypeScript). I have endpoints to send the file data to my backend C#. after uploading it return status code 200 but the file status still "Uploading" how can I change to "done".

```
customRequest({ file, onSuccess, onError }) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);
  axios.post('http://localhost:6788/api/upload', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  })
    .then(response => {
      // Update the file status to "done"
      file.status = 'done';
      if (onSuccess) {
        onSuccess(response.data, response);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      if (onError) {
        onError(error);
      }
    });
}
```

in the line that I update the status to done it throw compile error
Property 'status' does not exist on type 'File | RcFile'.
Property 'status' does not exist on type 'File'.ts(2339)

Please provide the solution for this issue